# How can I show that this complicated function is always positive between x=0 and x=2?

Tags: analysis

I have plotted the function

$$-2+2^{1-n}\left(\begin{array}{c}
\color{#FF0000}{16(n-1)(n-2)(x-1)^2(3+t^{-1/2})^{n-3}t^{-1}} \\
\color{#0000FF}{+4(n-1)(3+ t^{-1/2})^{n-2}t^{-1/2}} \\
\color{#04B404}{-16(n-1)(x-1)^2t^{-3/2}(3+t^{-1/2})^{n-2}} \\ 
\color{#FF0000}{+16(n-1)(n-2)(x-1)^2(3-t^{-1/2})^{n-3}t^{-1}} \\ 
\color{#0000FF}{-4(n-1)(3-t^{-1/2})^{n-2}t^{-1/2}} \\ 
\color{#04B404}{+16(n-1)(x-1)^2t^{-3/2}(3-t^{-1/2})^{n-2}}\end{array}\right)$$

(where $t=9-4x(x-2)$ and $n$ is a positive integer greater than 2)

for various different values of x, and it looks like it's always positive.

I have worked out its derivative, which has a zero at x=2. The value it attains at x=2 is, in fact positive. However, as this is a local minimum rather than a global one, it's not enough to prove that the function is always positive.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks quite uninviting. Depending on how rigorous you want to be, you could try to do it computationally.

Comment: Yes, very uninviting. What do you mean by 'do it computationally'? It doesn't have to be too rigorous.

Comment: Graphing it on some software, for example.

Comment: Trouble is, the value of $n$ varies. But I suppose I could think of a way around that, perhaps showing that for n=3 it's always positive (graphically) and then coming up with an argument to show that for increasing values of n, it gets more positive.

Comment: How did such a function come up?

Comment: Yikes that's pretty hard on the eyes.

Comment: Plug it into some computer algebra system and tell it to "simplify"? By the way is the star multiplication or convolution?

Comment: I edited it and put in some color so that it's a little easier to see which terms most easily match. Hopefully someone can take it from there.

Comment: It seems like you should factor $(3+t^{-1/2})^{n-3}-(3-t^{-1/2})^{n-3}$ out, which combines the terms of like colors.  The blue and green ones then get a factor $2t^{-1/2}$ while the red ones get a factor $2$  That makes a little less mess.

Comment: Thanks for useful edit. I think a sensible strategy would be to show (graphically) that for n=2 it's positive in that interval.

Then, for n->n+1, I could try to show that the bracketed term increases by a factor which is greater than 2. I'll give it a try.

This function came out as I played around with graph polynomials.